# Passing extra parameter to fs.createReadStream on data event

Tags: node.js, csv

Currently, I am trying to pass an extra parameter to the on Event that will be triggered once the data is fetched from the CSV file. I tried adding it as an extra paramter to the callback function but it always comes as undefined.

```
fs.createReadStream(values[i], {start: 118})
  .pipe(fastCSV())
  .on('data', function(data, myExtraParamter){
      logger.info(data);
      logger.info(myExtraParamter); --> this one shows an undefined

  })
  .on('end', function(data){
      logger.info("Reading all CSV file completed.");
  });
```

I would appreciate any pointers on how to pass data into the callback of the on Event.

Comment: If you're not married to the position of your extra argument, just use `bind`. Otherwise I can explain how to override the emit method... but that comes with a performance implications.

Comment: Thanks, @MichałKapracki for your response. Unfortunately, I have to do it this way and I would love if you can explain to me how I can override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, your requirement is to receive an additional parameter on the `data` event on a node.js stream.

What we need to clarify here - the solution depicted comes with, I expect, quite big performance impact, but we've all been in a situation where an external library forces us out of sensible solutions.

In order to achieve your goal, you need to override the way node.js stream will handle the `data` event - which in essence will lead to extending a [`PassThrough`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream with an overridden `EventEmitter.emit` method.

```
const {PassThrough} = require("streams");

class DataExtender extends PassThrough {
    constructor(...extra) {
        this._extra = extra;
    }

    emit(ev, ...args) {
        if (ev === 'data') return super.emit(ev, ...this._extra, ...args);
        super.emit(ev, ...args);
    }

}
```

This class will allow you to push any number of arguments you like to the consuming stream. The usage will require a minor modification and you're set:

```
fs.createReadStream(values[i], {start: 118})
    .pipe(fastCSV())
    .pipe(new DataExtender("extraParam1", "extraParam2")) // you set those on "pipe"
    .on('data', function(data, myExtraParamter, myOtherParamter) { // you get those on "data"
        logger.info(data);
        logger.info(myExtraParamter); // --> this won't show undefined anymore.
    })
    .on('end', function(data) { // BTW: data will be undefined here...
        logger.info("Reading all CSV file completed.");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped :)